# Query - What is the calc to determine "working days" from a "start date"

Tags: weekend

I'm asking this for a fellow team member. They are able to calculate the number of days from when the project started, but we need to exclude the weekends (Saturday & Sunday) from the StartDate. Right now, I am getting 8 days, but I know it should be 6 business days (Monday - Friday).

I hope I am explaining this properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which programming language? Which date and time library? Do you need to exclude public holidays too (will probably be harder)?